# Mooc objects within objects

Tags: java

I'm working on the mooc.fi assignments and I'm really stuck at the clock assignment.  I don't want a solution, but advice on how to reach my solution as I'm still learning and really need to figure out how to work through this.  If you're unfamiliar with mooc, the current section is on how to work with objects within objects.

It consists of three classes, the main creates the clock and the boundedcounter is what makes the clock tick.  I get it to print onto the screen, but when a custom starting input is entered it prints that first, then resets the value back to zero.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?  Sorry for the basic question, still trying to learn this java language!

**Main**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock clock = new Clock(23, 59, 50);

    int i = 0;
    while( i < 20) {
        System.out.println( clock );
        clock.tick();
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

**Clock**

```
public class Clock {

private BoundedCounter hours;
private BoundedCounter minutes;
private BoundedCounter seconds;

public Clock(int hoursAtBeginning, int minutesAtBeginning, int secondsAtBeginning) {
    // the counters that represent hours, minutes and seconds are created and set to have the correct initial values
    this.hours = new BoundedCounter(hoursAtBeginning);
    this.hours.setValue(hoursAtBeginning);

    this.minutes = new BoundedCounter(minutesAtBeginning);
    this.minutes.setValue(minutesAtBeginning);

    this.seconds = new BoundedCounter(secondsAtBeginning);
    this.seconds.setValue(secondsAtBeginning);


}

public void tick() { //increases the time

        this.seconds.next();

        if (this.seconds.getValue() == 0) {
            this.minutes.next();

            if (this.minutes.getValue() == 0) {
                this.hours.next();
            }
        }
    }

public String toString() {
    // returns the string representation
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
}
```

**BoundedCounter**

```
public class BoundedCounter {

private int value;
private int upperLimit;

public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit) {
    // write code here
    this.value = 0;
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
}

public void next() {
    // write code here
    if (value < upperLimit) {
        value++;
    } else {
        value = 0;
    }
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    if (value >= 0 && value <= upperLimit) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (value < 10) {
        return "0" + value;
    }
    return "" + value;
}
}
```

Comment: You're passing the current time to BoundedCounter, but BoundedCounter is expecting the upper bound, not the current time.

Comment: You know what's funny, I actually had that set correctly and then changed it.  Logic would suggest that the upperlimit of an hour is 23, for a minute is 59 and also for a seconds.  I manually set those, and then used my setValue() for the other tests.  Thanks for helping me guys!!!

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to take the short tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour. You can *upvote* multiple answers you find useful by clicking the adjacent up triangle, and *accept* one answer by clicking the adjacent checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the current time to BoundedCounter.

```
this.hours = new BoundedCounter(hoursAtBeginning);
this.minutes = new BoundedCounter(minutesAtBeginning);
this.seconds = new BoundedCounter(secondsAtBeginning);
```

But BoundedCounter is expecting the upper bound, not the current time.

```
public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit) {
```

Since whatever time you pass it is considered the upper limit, the next tick rolls over to 0:0:0.

Answer (score 0):

`BoundedCounter.next()` sets `value` to 0 if `value` is not less than `upperLimit`. Since the `Clock` constructor always initializes all `BoundedCounter` `value` values to be **equal to** `upperLimit`, the first call to `Clock.tick()` will cause all `BoundedCounter` objects to set their `value` values to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the corrections:

```
    this.hours = new BounedCounter(int upperLimit); 
    this.minutes = new BounedCounter(int upperLimit);
    this.seconds = new BounedCounter(int upperLimit);
```

the method `public void tick()` has to be composed as shown below, otherwise when the value of the minutes is 00 while the value of the seconds is 01, 02, ...59, the value of the hours will be increased with every second, and the result will be 01:00:01, 2:00:02, 3:00:03, etc.

```
public void tick() {
    this.seconds.next();
    if (this.seconds.getValue() == 0) {
        this.minutes.next();
    }
    if (this.minutes.getValue() == 0 && this.seconds.getValue() == 0) {
        this.hours.next();
    }
}
```